# Local Notification with Action button

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I downloaded and ran the sample from flutter local notifications on iOS and I was unable to see any action buttons, on iOS, I did not try on Android. I have a requirement to be able to snooze a notification.

[image]

[Flutter Local Notifications Github][2]

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications

I see that the code should support action buttons but I do not see them working.

Am I missing some configuration? The code I see is, I do not see any button when long pressing the action

```
  final List<DarwinNotificationCategory> darwinNotificationCategories =
  <DarwinNotificationCategory>[
    DarwinNotificationCategory(
      darwinNotificationCategoryText,
      actions: <DarwinNotificationAction>[
        DarwinNotificationAction.text(
          'text_1',
          'Action 1',
          buttonTitle: 'Send',
          placeholder: 'Placeholder',
        ),
      ],
    ),
    DarwinNotificationCategory(
      darwinNotificationCategoryPlain,
      actions: <DarwinNotificationAction>[
        DarwinNotificationAction.plain('id_1', 'Action 1'),
        DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
          'id_2',
          'Action 2 (destructive)',
          options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
            DarwinNotificationActionOption.destructive,
          },
        ),
        DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
          navigationActionId,
          'Action 3 (foreground)',
          options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
            DarwinNotificationActionOption.foreground,
          },
        ),
        DarwinNotificationAction.plain(
          'id_4',
          'Action 4 (auth required)',
          options: <DarwinNotificationActionOption>{
            DarwinNotificationActionOption.authenticationRequired,
          },
        ),
      ],
      options: <DarwinNotificationCategoryOption>{
        DarwinNotificationCategoryOption.hiddenPreviewShowTitle,
      },
    )
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `awesome_notifications` supports Notifications with ActionButtons. You can get the package here: [Link to package](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications)

Comment: its IOS setting not working